# Gigabyte AERO 17 XE5 i7-12700H/ RTX3070Ti is really hot and noisy?

Tags: laptop

at the moment I am using a MacBook Pro M1 Max Pro. For one project I must migrate to Windows 11, and I am thinking about switching to an Aero 17 with MiniLED +1000 nits (I work often in Lightroom, etc). I have read that this laptop is very hot and noisy, is this true? I know that MacBooks are